# How do I change my vote?

Tags: discussion, support

I confused one candidate for another, and voted for him ignorantly.
I wanted to change my vote. How do I do this?

Comment: Ron knows this, but for the sake of others:  Some discussion of the candidates can be seen here:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination .  Sadly new comments seem to be impossible.

Answer (score 14):

You can still go back to the election page and click on the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd choice buttons of other candidates to change your vote. You can do this as many times as you want before the election period ends.

If you don't want to vote for 3 different people, you can also select the same candidate for more than one of 1st, 2nd, and 3rd. (It doesn't make your vote count any more than it would normally.)